# can't do objdump for linux kernel image

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, arm, disassembly

For arm's N1 SDP (system design platform for N1 chip), after I build the software as directed by the `Getting Started`, I have an output file `linux/out/n1sdp/arch/arm64/boot/Image`.
I saw when I pass the file as kernel to qemu-system-aarch64, linux boot started and ran to some stage. so it is clearly arm64 code. The file starts like this when seen in hex data, ..

```
00000000: 4d5a 0091 ff3f 4914 0000 0800 0000 0000  MZ...?I.........
00000010: 0040 9b01 0000 0000 0a00 0000 0000 0000  .@..............
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 4152 4d64 4000 0000  ........ARMd@...
00000040: 5045 0000 64aa 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000  PE..d...........
00000050: 0000 0000 a000 0602 0b02 0214 0060 3001  .............`0.
00000060: 00d0 6a00 0000 0000 7850 2501 0010 0000  ..j.....xP%.....
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0002 0000  ................
00000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................ 
00000090: 0040 9b01 0010 0000 0000 0000 0a00 0000  .@..............
000000a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000c0: 0000 0000 0600 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 2e74 6578 7400 0000  .........text...
00000100: 0060 3001 0010 0000 0060 3001 0010 0000  .`0......`0.....
00000110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 2000 0060  ............ ..`
00000120: 2e64 6174 6100 0000 00d0 6a00 0070 3001  .data.....j..p0.
00000130: 00da 6100 0070 3001 0000 0000 0000 0000  ..a..p0.........
00000140: 0000 0000 4000 00c0 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  ....@.... ... ..
00000150: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
00000160: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
00000170: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
00000180: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
00000190: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
000001a0: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
000001b0: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
000001c0: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
000001d0: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
000001e0: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
000001f0: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
00000200: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
00000210: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
00000220: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
00000230: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
00000240: 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5 1f20 03d5  . ... ... ... ..
```

From the first pattern, I can see it's the linux's start.S code (The first two bytes are meaning-less jump instruction to make the magic pattern "MZ", I learned this before). Here is the problem. I think I've done this in the past before, but when I tried to disassemble it I get error as below.

> ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/N1SDP/arm-reference-platforms$
> aarch64-none-elf-objdump -d linux/out/n1sdp/arch/arm64/boot/Image
> aarch64-none-elf-objdump: linux/out/n1sdp/arch/arm64/boot/Image: file
> format not recognized

What's the correct command to disassemble it?

ADD : I tried disassembling using a web site's service (https://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/) and it correctly disassembles it. I can see the mark MZ and the branch instruction. So it should be possible to disassemble it with aarch-none-eabi-objdump I think.:
[image]

Comment: An MZ executable?  On ARM64?!  Very surprising to say the least.

Comment: @fuz see https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm64/kernel/head.S line 74 and the preceding comment.

Comment: Try `objdump -b binary -D`.  You might need to manually adjust the load address (`--adjust-vma=...`) so the addresses match.

Comment: It's a PECOFF header as used by Windows, so a Windows ARM PECOFF disassembler maybe able to disassemble it.  It should at least see what an ARM UEFI loader would actually execute.

Comment: I just found, on my ubuntu machine, the file /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-126-generic starts with "MZ" and the first 512 bytes ends with 0x55aa(indicating it contains bootstrap code). But the Image file in my question doesn't show the 0x55aa. Probably because it uses UEFI/GPT method, anyway..

Comment: please see my updated question. an website correctly disassembles it.

Comment: fuz's comment above explains how to disassemble it as a binary with `objdump`.  Note that it's not going to be loaded as a binary on your Neoverse N1 device. Since it uses UEFI to boot it will load it as a PECOFF image.

Comment: `aarch64-none-elf-objdump -b binary -D Image` gives me `can't disassemble for architecture UNKNOWN!`. I tried it with objdump (for x86_64) but the same.

Comment: @RossRidge I searched for ARM PECOFF disassembler in vain. Can you help me find it? I'm not sure if this is it : https://binaryum.com/faq/

Comment: Use `aarch64-none-elf-objdump --help` and look for the `supported architectures:` listing near the end. Pick the one that most closely matches your device and use it with the `-m` option to specify an architecture. You should be able to build a version of `objdump` targeting Windows ARM64 that can disassemble the kernel, but I don't know where you'd find an already built version. The ARM64 version  of `dumbin` from Visual  Studio should be able to disassemble it, but that only works on Windows.  IDA Pro should be able to disassemble it, but it's not free and requires Windows.

Comment: @RossRidge hi , thanks, following your suggestion, I added -m aarch64 and I can see the disassembled code! so the command was `aarch64-none-elf-objdump -b binary -D Image -m aarch64`. I didn't know we have to supply the machine type in this binary case. you can post your short answer so that I can select it.

Comment: @fuz thanks for the help. it was `aarch64-none-elf-objdump -b binary -D Image -m aarch64`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the helps in the comments.
The correct method for disassembling Image file was :

aarch64-none-elf-objdump -b binary -D Image -m aarch64